# shiny: use data generated in renderRHandsontable({}) in another renderRHandsontable({}) expression

Tags: r, shiny, data-manipulation, rhandsontable, reactive

below is a schemata of what I would like to achieve
     data <- read.csv("data.csv")

```
 output$table1 <- renderRHandsontable({
 data <- data*2
 data_table <- filter(data, "ID1")
 rhandsontable(data_table)})

 output$table2 <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(data)})
```

I want to read some data, manipulate (costly) it in a rhandsontable and use the date in another rhandsontable. Whenever I update data in table1 table 2 should also be updated. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code does what you want. Here the 2nd table is rendered only after you make some change in the 1st table.

The ui.R is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("Table1"),
  br(),
  br(),
  rHandsontableOutput("Table2")
)
```

The server. R is as follows:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #Render !st table at the begining 
  output$Table1 <- renderRHandsontable({

    rhandsontable(datasets::mtcars, height = 400, selectCallback = TRUE, readOnly = FALSE)
  })


  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$Table1$changes$changes[[1]][[1]])){# Render the 2nd table only after the data in the 1st table changes

      output$Table2 <- renderRHandsontable({

        rhandsontable(hot_to_r(input$Table1), height = 400, readOnly = TRUE)

      }) 
    }

  })

}
```

Hope this helps!